# Parsing text file with a complicated delimiter

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, text, io

I have a text file containing tweets in the following format

```
['RT @abcd: Name another swing group who can sell out Bob Field. Thank you.', 'Thanks to amazing supporters like @Bob Community Development, eligible New Yorkers can use NYC #FreeTaxPrep to get… SomeURL']
```

I want to convert the string to a list of individual tweets.

As I see it, the delimiter is a single quote,followed by a comma, followed by a space, followed by a single quote.

My code is as follows:

```
opened_file = open('file_name.txt')
read_file = opened_file.read()
split_dataset = read_file.split(" \', \' ")
```

However, when I test the length of the resulting list, I get a size of only one, meaning no parsing has taken place.

```
>>> len(split_dataset)
1
```

Comment: I don't think you need to escape the single quotes if you are using double quotes for your string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should split using this string: `read_file.split("', '")` (no leading or trailing spaces, no backslash).

This will not take care of the leading and trailing characters (`'`, `[` and `]`). While you can take care of them manually, it looks like the list was written to file with a python module or function. Chances are you can use the same module to read directly into a list. For instance, using `yaml`, for your 1-line file, but works with multi-lines files too:

```
import yaml

with  open('file_name.txt') as opened_file:
    for line in opened_file.readlines():
        split_dataset = yaml.load(line)
        print len(split_dataset)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data is stored in almost JSON, except that single quotes are used instead of double quotes. Perhaps it's best to "fix" the data to look like real JSON and then handle it with `json` module:

```
import json
read_file = read_file.replace('"', '\\"').replace("'", '"')
split_dataset = json.loads(read_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

The text file was written with "stringified" Python list syntax.  `ast.literal_eval` can convert it back to a real Python list:

```
>>> s = '''['RT @abcd: Name another swing group who can sell out Bob Field. Thank you.', 'Thanks to amazing supporters like @Bob Community Development, eligible New Yorkers can use NYC #FreeTaxPrep to get… SomeURL']'''
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval(s)
['RT @abcd: Name another swing group who can sell out Bob Field. Thank you.', 'Thanks to amazing supporters like @Bob Community Development, eligible New Yorkers can use NYC #FreeTaxPrep to get… SomeURL']
```

This will read and convert each line:

```
import ast
with open('file_name.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        L = ast.literal_eval(line)
        # do something with the list
```